# Use ContentProvider or Intent to send data from an application to other？

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I want to send data from application A to application B. There are two methods I can use to go about this.

One method is to use `startService()`. I put the data into an `Intent`, through the `startService()` to send the data. Application B gets the data and writes it to the database.

The second method is to use a `ContentProvider` to write the data to the application B's database. Because there is so much data to send, I use the child thread to write the data.

They all work ok. Please help me to judge which method is better.

Intent method:

```
private ExecutorService mSingleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG,
            "onStartCommand  #" + this.toString() + "  #"
                    + intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_APP_CODE, -1) + "  #"
                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    recordDataOfIntent(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

private void recordDataOfIntent(Intent intent) {
    int dataType = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_DATA_TYPE, -1);
    switch (dataType) {
        case DataConstants.APP_START: {
            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(getRecordAppStartRunnable(intent));
            break;
        }
        case DataConstants.USER_ACTION: {
            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(getRecordUserActionRunnable(intent));
            break;
        }
        case DataConstants.PAGE_VISIT: {
            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(getRecordPageVisitRunnable(intent));
            break;
        }
        case DataConstants.EVENT: {
            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(getRecordEventRunnable(intent));
            break;
        }
        case DataConstants.KV_EVENT: {
            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(getRecordKVEventRunnable(intent));
            break;
        }
        case DataConstants.EXCEPTION: {
            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(getRecordExceptionRunnable(intent));
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ContentProvider method:

```
    private ExecutorService mSingleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri arg0) {
    int option = mUriMatcher.match(arg0);
    switch (option) {
        case URI_TABLE_EVENT_CODE: {
            return URI_TABLE_EVENT_TYPE;
        }
        default: {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + arg0);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri arg0, final ContentValues arg1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "insert");
    int option = mUriMatcher.match(arg0);
    switch (option) {
        case URI_TABLE_EVENT_CODE: {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DBUtil.addKVEventInfo(mDatabase, arg1);                     
                }
            };

            mSingleThreadExecutor.execute(runnable);

            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
    return getEventTableUri();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    mDatabase = DBUtil.initDatabase(getContext());
    mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_EVENT, URI_TABLE_EVENT_CODE);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use ContentProvider if other application needs to access your application data.Use Intent to send and open other application from your application

Answer (score 2):

Because you have so much data to send, i would suggest that you implement ContentProvider in Application A where the data resides and use ContentResolver in Application B to access the data at any time it needs.

Alternatively, you could bundle and send all the required data using an Intent but you have to be sure that you have bundled all the data fields without missing anything - which can be a bit too much to ask aPriori.

So, looks like ContentProvider might be a better solution for you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks! Maybe what I saied not clear. I hava so much data to send means I hava to send many intents or use so many times ContentProvider to write data at a few time, so I use the child thread to do the work.

Comment: @uu1r1cl Do you need to show any Application-B screens when Application-A sends an intent to Application-B?

Comment: No,no screends to show when Application-A sends an intent to Application-B.

Answer (score 0):

To share persistent data the content provider is a good choice for something other applications may use in the future. For example contacts. It is more structured. If you don't plan to have this data used by other applications then I would go with the service because it may have less overhead.

Comment: Thanks! Other application only need to insert data to the application B's database.